# Wireshark does not capture HTTP on 8080

Tags: linux, http, network-monitoring, wireshark

I am running Wireshark on my linux machine and i have simple python web server running on localhost:8080

I am capturing only local port 8080. When i open browser on localhost:8080 wireshark captures huge amount of tcp communication (as page loads with all resources) but there`s no HTTP only TCP...

Why i cannot capture HTTP on custom port ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the TCP stream, then select **Decode as...**. Go to the **Transport** tab, if you aren't already on it. From the list, select **HTTP**. Click **OK** and enjoy.

[image: Wireshark: Decode As]

Comment: Wireshark, by default, considers traffic to or from ports 80 and 8080 (as well as 3128, 3132, 5985, 8088, 11371, 1900, 2869, and 2710) as HTTP traffic, so it *shouldn't* be necessary to use "Decode as..." to recognize port 8080 traffic as HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

> Why i cannot capture HTTP on custom port

You can capture on a custom port just fine.

I would bet that you are capturing on the wrong interface.

If your requests are going to 127.0.0.1 tcp/8080 and you are capturing on the `eth0` interface, then you simply won't see any traffic because `eth0` is not the loopback adapter.

Capture on the loopback interface, or capture on the pseudo-interface that combines all interfaces  named `any`.

Comment: i am capturing on lo interface (Ubuntu).