# How to decode traffic as NTLM protocol in Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, ntlm

I'm trying to debug `NTLM` authentication issue. One of my ideas was to capture the network traffic and look thougth it. In my case `NTLM` authentication is going over non-stardart port (6901). Of course, Wireshark can't detect it. But there is **no** `NTLM` (`NTLMSSP`) protocol **in the list** in `Decode as` menu. I can't do like [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/505840/wireshark-does-not-capture-http-on-8080).
Is there a way to ask Wireshark to decode traffic as `NTLM`?
Or I need to modify captured traffic, e.g. change `TCP` port or somehow another?

Comment: Wireshark does support NTLM SSP protocol https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/n/ntlmssp.html

Comment: It supports, but how to decode raw byte traffic as `NTLM`?

Comment: Have you got a very old version of Wireshark then?

Comment: I checked for updates rigth now again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure which ports NTLMSSP actually uses, but you could try this Lua-script to register the NTLMSSP-dissectors to your custom port.

```
local tcp_port_table = DissectorTable.get("tcp.port")
local tcp_ntlmssp_dis = tcp_port_table:get_dissector(445)
tcp_port_table:add(6901, tcp_ntlmssp_dis)
```

Save this to a file - e.g. ntlmssp.lua - and tell Wireshark to load it, e.g.

```
$ wireshark -X lua_script:ntlmssp.lua -r trace.pcap
```

You might have to change the port 445 to what's really needed or register additional ports by adding additional lines like `tcp_port_table:get_dissector(4711)`. If you need UDP as well, do the same for UDP.

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work, and have not been successful. What is the proper port for NTLMSSP? If this technique works, it doesn't appear its 445, and I've tried a bunch of others.

Answer (score 0):

Alexander Janssen's LUA script doesn't work because it's getting the protocol by port number (445 - SMB/CIFS), but can be altered to register the NTLMSSP dissector by name like this:

```
local tcp_port_table = DissectorTable.get("tcp.port")
local tcp_ntlmssp_dis = Dissector.get("ntlmssp")
tcp_port_table:add(6901, tcp_ntlmssp_dis)
```

6901 being the port that the NTLMSSP service is running on. For protocols other than NTLMSSP, anything from the list at https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/ should work instead of "ntlmssp".

I tested this successfully last week when analyzing traffic to a different custom NTLMSSP service.